# JS cant access global variable inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to make a simple webscraper using Node and Puppeteer to get the titles of posts on reddit, but am having issues accessing a global variable, SUBREDDIT_NAME from within only one function, extractItems(). It works fine with every other function, but for that one I have to make a local variable with the same value for it to work.

Am I completely misunderstanding variable scope in Javascript?

I have tried everything I can think of, and the only thing that works is to create a local variable inside of extractedItems() with the value of "news", otherwise I get nothing.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const SUBREDDIT = (subreddit_name) => `https://reddit.com/r/${subreddit_name}/`;
const SUBREDDIT_NAME= "news";


function extractItems() {
  const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*='r/${SUBREDDIT_NAME}/comments/'] h3`);
  const items = [];
  for (let element of extractedElements) {
    items.push(element.innerText);
  }
  return items;
}

async function scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(
  page,
  extractItems,
  itemTargetCount,
  scrollDelay = 1000,
) {
  let items = [];
  try {
    let previousHeight;5
    while (items.length < itemTargetCount) {
      items = await page.evaluate(extractItems);
      previousHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
      await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
      await page.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`);
      await page.waitFor(scrollDelay);
    }
  } catch(e) { }
  return items;
}

(async () => {
  // Set up browser and page.
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 926 });

  // Navigate to the demo page.
  await page.goto(SUBREDDIT(SUBREDDIT_NAME));

  // Scroll and extract items from the page.
  const items = await scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(page, extractItems, 100);

  // Save extracted items to a file.
  fs.writeFileSync('./items.txt', items.join('\n') + '\n');

  // Close the browser.
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I expect a text file with the 100 first found titles, but it only works when I hardcode the subreddit into the extractItems() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `extractItems` function is converted to a string (without processing the template literal) and executed in the pages context where there is no `SUBREDDIT_NAME` variable.

You can fix that by doing something like this:

```
function extractItems(name) {
  const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*='r/${name}/comments/'] h3`);
  const items = [];
  for (let element of extractedElements) {
    items.push(element.innerText);
  }
  return items;
}

page.evaluate(`(${extractItems})(${SUBREDDIT_NAME})`)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(${extractItems})(${SUBREDDIT_NAME})` or (`(${extractItems})(${SUBREDDIT_NAME})`)?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher Yes, that is correct, I've made an edit.

Comment: Why do you use string concatenation? You can call it like this: `page.evaluate(extractItems, SUBREDDIT_NAME)`